# Concatenating Files And Insert a Word In Between Files

Tags: windows, powershell, concatenation, gzip

I have around 3000 .gz files that I need to concatenate with the word "break" in between each file in PowerShell.

```
cat *gz > allmethods.txt
```

This concatenates all my files but does not leave any space in between. I need to add a word in between each file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Get-Content -Raw *gz | 
  ForEach-Object { $_ + 'break' } |
    Set-Content -Encoding utf8 allmethods.txt
```

- On Windows, `cat` is a built-in alias for the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet; `-Raw` reads each matching file *in full*, as a single, multiline string.
- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call concatenates each file's content, reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) variable with verbatim string `break` and outputs the result.

  - Note: This assumes that each input file has a *trailing newline* and that you don't want an empty line before each occurrence of `break`; to in effect insert a newline between the file's content and `break`, use `$_; 'break'` instead.
  - The *last* file's content will also be followed by `break`.
- The [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) call saves all strings it receives to the specified output file, using the specified encoding via the `-Encoding` parameter - adjust as needed.