# How to cat all files in a directory except first line?

Tags: windows, powershell, concatenation, gzip

I have around 3,000 gzip folders that I need to concatenate into one file except for the first line of each file. I also need to have the word "break" in between each file.

[Concatenating Files And Insert a Word In Between Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092135/concatenating-files-and-insert-a-word-in-between-files)

I asked this a few days ago. I need to do the exact same thing, just taking out the first line. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you'll need to pipe each file to `Get-Content` individually and omit the `-Raw` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem *gz |ForEach-Object {
  $_ |Get-Content |Select-Object -Skip 1
  'break'
} |Select-Object -SkipLast 1 |Set-Content -Encoding utf8 allmethods.txt
```

The `Select-Object -Skip 1` command will discard the first line from each file read, and `Select-Object -SkipLast 1` will remove the last trailing `break` from the entire output stream.

Comment: How would I do the same thing, except ONLY take the first line?

Comment: @MakeenMajlis Change `Select-Object -Skip 1` to `Select-Object -First 1`